# php - table click button, popup to display details

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to show details data(using popup) when I click the view button in table in each rows?

button code

```
echo '<button href="student.php?id="'.$row['mactrixNo'].'" onclick=document.getElementById("id02").style.display="block">View</button>';
```

popup code

```
<div id="id02" class="logform">
    <table border="1" class="tg w-100">
        <tr>
            <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                $query='select *
                from student
                where mactrixNo="'.$_GET['id'].'"';
            }
            ?>
```

I can't get the 'id' when popup

Comment: are you using bootstrap css/js?

Comment: yes using bootstrap

Comment: ok I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap provides the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript you need to achieve this.
This is from v4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So long as you have the CSS and JS in your `<head>` section, all you need to do is edit the content!

Comment: But I still got a problem, can't get the data from database when popup

Comment: `echo` your content in the `div.modal-body` , replacing the `...`